# iPhone 5c: no edge mobile data after 7.1 update

Tags: ios, internet, cellular-data, iphone

I have an iPhone 5c, recently updated using iTunes to version 7.1, and now all I can see is 3G or 4G, no edge option in mobile data, how can I restore it?

Comment: Where are you looking? Edge hasn't been an option to my knowledge in the last several versions. I only have an option for LTE, not even 3G. Can you post a screenshot of where you believe it should be?

Comment: @tubedogg technically it's my friend's iphone, he told me to ask the question, secondly he swears that he had it before updating his IOS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can choose the following items:

- Cellular data (on / off)
- Data roaming
- LTE or 3G or 4G switch, based on your carrier

The option to enable edge or GPRS hasn't been available since iOS 3.x (I have had my first iPhone then and never changed to any other phone, I'm not sure if it ever was an option.)

Comment: technically it's my friend's iphone, he told me to ask the question, secondly he swears that he had it before updating his IOS, I'll tell him to contact the carrier